# MySQL Workbench hang on fetching more than some size of data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

On my notebook installed Workbench x64 6.1.7. I connect to remote MySQL server over ssh. When on server was MySQL 5.5 everything was good. But after upgrade MySQL 5.5 to 5.6.19, Workbrench started to hang when I run query with data which size is more than some size. For example, "select id from my_table" work fine, "select * from my_table" does not work (Workbench wait fetching infinitely and it can be closed (or make something else) only if I kill it), but "select * from my_table limit 10" work fine.
I did mysql_upgrade on server, but it didn't resolve problem.
All local (on server) queries (from php and cmd line (via putty)) work fine.

Comment: Maybe you have a big table? Or one with big blobs?

Comment: No, for example one table has 92 rows, and I select only non-text/blob fields - datetime, varchar(50-250), int types - work fine. But if I add one more varchar(1000) field - hang.

Comment: Already without varchar(1000) field doesn't work :(

Comment: Any ideas? Very need help

Comment: No idea, what the reason could be. We've released MySQL Workbench 6.2 beta (soon GA). Try this. Maybe it solves the problem. If not file a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com so we can take a closer look.

Comment: Installed 6.2 - the same result, fetching infinitely. Maybe it is some options in Debian or mysql on server, which do not output some size of traffic?

Comment: I installed NEW server (Ubuntu 14) with 5.6.19 MySQL, localy I update Workbench to 6.2.3. And the same problem!

Comment: We have same problem accessing remote MySQL, in many tables we cannot retrieve more then ~100 rows.

Comment: I install new windows 8.1 and the same problem!! Via two ethernet cards, two internet providers.

Comment: Same problem here: MySQL WB over SSH to MySQL 5.6 (had no problems over 5.1 before upgrade to 5.5 => 5.6 process). We have 7 users who access the DB using the same credentials...all from the same building.  3 of us have the exact problem described, and 4 of us have no problems at all.  On some tables, the affected machines can only query up to 15 rows, on other tables as many as 50 rows...doesn't appear to be byte-size related...as the 50 rows has more data than the 15...although the 15 row table does have a TEXT column (with very little text per row)...weirdest problem I've ever seen.

Comment: The same problem in new version 6.3.3 !!!!

Comment: The same problem in new version 6.3.4 TOO !!!!

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so we had the same problem. It was finicky. Out of the 8 developers we had try to connect to MySQL, it was evenly divided with 4 having problems, 4 no problems at all. The O/S having the problem was a mix of Win7 and Win8.

We were able to solve the problem for the developers having problems by installing MySQL WorkBench 6.0.9

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/6.0.html

Hopefully that solution will work for anyone else having the problem as well.

Comment: Yes, this old version work for us too. But it is only temp solution. ORACLE - please resolve thos problem, because we need your new futures in last version of WB.